# Transferring a large byte array between C# and JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, sockets

The system I'm currently working on involves passing images from one C#-based application to another, where the second C# application sends the image to a JavaScript webbrowser client.

The first two applications communicate via sockets, so sending a large byte array between these application is fairly easy. My problem arises when I try to forward the file to the JavaScript client. I tried to use a XMLHttpRequest object at first. But it seems the XMLHttpRequest.responseText buffer can't handle the large byte file it's receiving.

So now I'm looking for an alternative approach to this problem. Preferably one that doesn't involve third-party libraries or software. I was thinking of trying to compress the data, or using websockets. But so far I haven't found a conclusive answer. Do you guys know of any?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `alternate` approach would be use base64 instead for larger files and send it as a parameter rather then doing the things in url

Comment: In this context, how large is _"large"_?

Comment: What are you doing on JS after receiving the byte array? show it as an image? manipulate it? If you want to show it, you will hit a lot of problems because you will need to use it as an embedded image in base64 and it will kill the browser, so may be it's a better idea to host in your second app the IIS hostable core and use it to serve images, this way you can just link to them.

Comment: You can try doing chunked tranfer encoding where responses will be chunked and can be accumulated at receiver

Comment: The JS client only shows the image it receives, nothing more. The byte array is around 125000 bytes large at the moment. It could become even larger in the future. Casting it to a base64string only doubles the size, for some reason.

Comment: Have you considered setting the 'responseType' property of XMLHttpRequest to 'ArrayBuffer'?
reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

Comment: Andrea, that helped me out. Thank you!